# Is there a list of possible categories returned by the Mapbox Search SDK?

Tags: mapbox

I found this list of categories that you can search for, but it doesn't seem to include all categories (e.g. Monument is missing): [POI Category Coverage](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/#point-of-interest-category-coverage). Is there a definitive list of all possible categories that could be returned with a search result, or would there not be many more than the common ones listed here? I'd like to attach a custom icon to search results, but for that I need to know the possible return values to match icons to.

Thanks.

Comment: "The Geocoding API's POI category search feature is constantly being updated, and the current list of POI categories is subject to change. Since this is the case, data may change and should not be considered canonical."

Comment: Ah ok. So no there isn't, and don't rely on this list. Thanks.